# How to show progress while uploading file to GCS in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, progress, resume, pause

I tried [this](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage) code for uploading file on GCS in android . This code is running perfectly and uploading file on bucket. 
Now I want to check progress with pause ,resume and internet on/off handling . 
I search alot on internet but did not find any perfect solution.

**Code**

```
CloudStorage.uploadFile("upload-recording", "/storage/sdcard0/Download/images.jpg",this,file);

public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String filePath,Context context,File file_use)
            throws Exception {

        this_context = context;
        this_file = file_use;
        Storage storage = getStorage();

        StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
        object.setBucket(bucketName);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            String contentType = URLConnection
                    .guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
            InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,
                    stream);

            Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(
                    bucketName, null, content);
            insert.setName(file.getName());

            insert.execute();
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you find a way to pause/resume handling for gcs bucket file upload?

Answer (score 2):

**Try CustomInputStream to get Status of data read and display it using service .**

```
public class ProgressNotifyingInputStream extends InputStream {
    private InputStream wrappedStream;
    private int count = 0;
    private int totalSize;
    File file;
    public ProgressNotifyingInputStream(File file)
     {
       this.file=file;
      }
    /**
     * Creates a new notifying outputstream which wraps an existing one.
     * When you write to this stream the callback will be notified each time when
     * updateAfterNumberBytes is written.
     * 
     * @param stream the outputstream to be wrapped
     * @param totalSize the totalsize that will get written to the stream
     */



     wrappedStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    public ProgressNotifyingInputStream(InputStream stream, int totalSize) {
        if(stream==null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if(totalSize == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("totalSize argument cannot be zero");
        }
        this.wrappedStream = stream;
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
    }


    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        count++;
        return wrappedStream.read();
    }

    /**
     * Get progress from 0 to 100
     * @return
     */
    public int getProgress() {
        return count * 100 / totalSize;
    }

}
```

**And i your Code just call**

```
InputStream stream=new ProgressNotifyingInputStream (file);
```

Comment: thanyou for the quick response. Actually I tried this like   ProgressNotifyingInputStream stream;
     stream = new FileInputStream(file); but there is an error which is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileInputStream to ProgressNotifyingInputStream" please guide me.

Comment: ok thanks its working. but can I resume this uploading through this code?